# XP Restart After Power Failure

Tags: windows-xp, bios, power-management

I've almost got my power settings sorted and was hoping someone could help?

If I'm running XP and the power is cut, when the power is restored my machine auto restarts (this is what I want!)

However, if I shutdown my machine properly (from the start menu & without touching the PC power button!), then switch the power off at the socket, then switch the power back on, the PC does not automatically restart.

It's like the BIOS(?) receives a message saying "aha, genuine shutdown and not a power cut, therefore do not restart on power restore."

I want my PC to restart every time it sees power restored from the socket?

Any way round this? Anyone seen this before?  I've upgraded my BIOS.

Comment: So your saying you want the computer to power on when there is power to the socket? Forgive me but then how would the pc ever stay off?

Comment: "I want my PC to restart everytime it sees power restored from the socket?" So 1. Shutdown the PC via windows and it stays switched off. 2. Flick the power off at the plug and it stays off (Surprisingly!) 3. If there's a power cut it stays off ... and then ... 1. When the power is restored it automatically boots up

Comment: @Systech - Sounds like he wants to do like I have mine setup.  I shutdown at night, then flip the power strip off that it's plugged into (to cut all the parasitic draw).  Then I walk in the next morning, flip the power strip switch back on and everything autostarts.

Comment: That's it Brian.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so I second Revolter's answer (BIOS setting) -- however, most BIOSes I've seen with the option (not all of them offer this whatsoever) have three settings for their "Restart After Power Interruption" option:

(1) Stay Off

(2) Power On

(3) Last State (If Previously Off, Stay Off; If Previously On, Turn Back On)

This is the right way to do it (choose option 2, obviously). BIOS support is required.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old computer with a BIOS setting (under Power Management Panel) saying :

```
SYSTEM AFTER AC BACK : STAY-OFF / FULL-ON
```

This is what you are looking for, its a BIOS feature, you need  to have something similar to this under your BIOS settings.

Comment: I'm on the latest Bios, and the only option I get is to restart after a power break. This doesn't work if I manually power down the PC within Windows.

Comment: not all Bios's have that option... the "restart after a power break" only mean "restart after a power cut".

Answer (score 0):

You could just leave your computer on all the time. Never shut it off. Just set it to sleep often and it will use little power.

That way, when the power goes out your computer will always have been on previously and will restart right away.

Comment: I could, but that's not what I'm after!